# How attach html-element to mouse using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I attach html-element to mouse cursor using jQuery. This should be something like 'draggable', but I want that element clung to the cursor after mouse double-click and to follow the cursor until the left mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Keep in mind that this may be confusing to most users, who are used to the click-drag-and-release interface of most modern operating systems.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll want to use `.mousemove()` and `.offset()`.

```
$("#clickedElement").dblclick(function () {
    var $someElement = $("#elementToCling");
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        $someElement.offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX });
    }).click(function () {
        $(this).unbind("mousemove");
    });
});
```

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/EbbxA/

Comment: Alternative demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a4eFE/ because I was bored and it looked cool.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted. But what if I want to be able to use "draggable" options, like a "snap", "revert", "containment", etc. How do I do this?

Comment: You'll have to hack the actual plugin code for jQueryUI.  It seems like it shouldn't be too difficult - just find where mousedown and mouseup are bound, and replace with dblclick and click.  Seems like this would be a handy feature for draggable to have built in.  Post back if you accomplish it!